# Is there a word to describe someone who protests or donates to make themselves look good?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Like someone who is disingenuous, someone who posts on social media about how much money they have donated or how they care about xyz when they don’t- they’re just doing it to feign altruism

Comment: Lack of research is the only possible justification for someone’s voting you down; they have offered no explanation and have ignored the guidance to be encouraging to newcomers. On the contrary, I believe your choice of words (disingenuous, feign altruism) to show research or at least  reflection and consideration. So please ignore the mutely negative downvote and continue to patronise the site. The site needs literate folk such as yourself. I have compensated for the negativity.

Comment: Sounds like a *humble brag*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin This is the opposite of a humble brag. Humble brag is when you make a self-deprecating statement as a way to brag about something.

Comment: A fake do-gooder.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are of seemingly charitable behaviour motivated not by charity but by a wish to seem generous and to gain favour.

Such a person is a **poser** or **poseur**

> [Collns](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/poseur)
> You can describe someone as a poseur when you think that they behave in an insincere or exaggerated way because they want to make a particular impression on other people.
> [disapproval]

The words convey a general meaning of adopting an attitude or behaviour that is manipulative or insincere. For example:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/poser-vs-poseur-history)
> *The word is almost always used with a negative connotation, conveying the skepticism we have for those who put on airs*

Answer (score 1):

> **performative**
> *adjective*
> ...
> 2. made or done for show (as to bolster one's own image or make a positive impression on others)
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/performative)

Answer (score 1):

A current phrase is “virtue signalling”—

Definitions from Oxford Languages ·
vir·tue sig·nal·ing
noun DEROGATORY
noun: virtue signalling
the public expression of opinions or sentiments intended to demonstrate one's good character or social conscience or the moral correctness of one's position on a particular issue.
"it's noticeable how often virtue signaling consists of saying you hate things"

Answer (score 0):

What about the word *hypocrite*?

> [**hypocrite**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypocrite)
> *noun*
> 1: a person who puts on a false appearance of virtue or religion
> 2: a person who acts in contradiction to his or her stated beliefs or feelings